# C# Console.ReadKey read numbers greater than 9

Tags: c#, .net, console, console.readkey

Im working with ConsoleKeyInfo in C# but i have problems with Console.ReadKey when I try to write numbers greater than 9 in the console, for example

```
ConsoleKeyInfo number;
Console.Write("Write a number: ");
number = Console.ReadKey();
```

If i want to write 10 or 11... the console only reads the "1"

I dont wanna use Console.ReadLine because I don want to press "Enter" for each number.

Is there another way to use Console.ReadKey to wait maybe 1 second before continue?

Thanks

Comment: You can type `10<Enter>` (only one Enter) and read it with `ReadLine`. Is that ok for you?

Comment: Right, because `ReadKey` only reads a *single* key. How is the computer to know that you're finished entering the number unless you press a key to indicate that? It used to be called the "Any" key, now it's called "Enter".

Comment: Console.Readkey by definition only reads one character. From MSDN: '...Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user'.

Comment: How will you know a number has been finished being entered then?

Comment: @elmer: tell us what you're trying to do. Explain why ReadLine won't cut it, what's that 1 second delay for, and why you though ReadKey would help. Help us help you.

Comment: @elmer Let us know how it turned out

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is use `Console.ReadLine()`. There's no way the program will know you have finished the number.

**UPDATE**

If you have a fixed length number (i.e. a 13-digit ISBN), you can use ReadKey, but like this:

```
string isbn = "";
while (isbn.Length < 13)
{
    isbn += Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
}
```

Comment: Well, what if the number is, say, a 13-digit ISBN? The program *knows* to finish by the 13th digit.

Comment: And the program cant wait a second before continue after the 1st key is pressed?

Comment: @Martinho - while that statement is correct, it's not what the OP asks. There's no indication of whether there is a limit on the size of number or that the number is *always* the same number of digits long.

Comment: @elmer - the problem with waiting is that you might be too quick for some people so they might not have chance to complete a long number "123456780987634734" - for example, especially if they are double checking they've got it right.

Comment: @Martinho - Just added some code to handle fixed length inputs with ReadKey.

Comment: @Chris: But "There's no way..." is not correct. There are ways. It can know the length, it can stop when any non-digit key is pressed, or it can use a time limit (ugh). I agree that ReadLine is the best solution (or something like [Mono.Readline](http://mono-readline.sourceforge.net/)), but "There's no way" is wrong. My first comment wasn't as clear as I expected :(

Comment: @Martinho - I didn't say anything about "There's no way...". I agree there *are* ways, but we need to know more about what the OP wants to do so we can make a constructive suggestion,

Comment: @Chris and @Martinho. I agree that there are always ways. I said "there's no way" to do like the OP wants. You see, if you stop reading when the user types in a non number digit, isn't that the same work as an Enter key? If you know the exact length, I posted an update that handles that, but that might not apply to OP.

Comment: @elmer I really don't think that the timing approach is a good solution, though it can be implemented. Specify what you want to achieve (final goal), tell more about your problem. Why do you want to avoid the Enter Key at the end of the input?

Answer (score 2):

As the comments on the question say, `Console.ReadKey` only reads a single *key* by definition. You will need to use a different function if you want to get more input from the console. Try something like this, for instance:

```
Console.Write("Write a number: ");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
int num = 0;
if (line != null)
    num = int.Parse(line);
```

That's a start, with minimal error checking. See what you can get from there.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you have to call `cki = Console.ReadKey(true)` multiple times.

```
      ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
      string userNumber = "";

      while(true)
      {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Press more than one key:");
        cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if(cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
          System.Console.WriteLine("GOOD BYE!");
          Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
          if(char.IsNumber(cki.KeyChar) || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
          {
            while(char.IsNumber(cki.KeyChar))
            {
              Console.Write(cki.KeyChar);
              userNumber += (cki.KeyChar).ToString();
              cki = Console.ReadKey(true);  // !!! Main idea 
            }
              System.Console.WriteLine();
              System.Console.WriteLine($"Your number is: {userNumber}");
              Environment.Exit(0);
          } 
          else
          {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Wrong symbol! Input a number!");
          }
        }
      }
```